# Termination due to memory error from debugger on adding label to scrollview in iphone5s

Tags: ios

My app hangs and I won't be able to perform any action when I add a label programmatically to my scrollview which is created by using auto layout in xib .After some seconds the app terminates with a memory warning saying "Message from debugger terminated due to memory error"

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   _hosStartDateLbl = [[UILabel alloc] init];
}

-(IBAction)hosSwitchSelected:(id)sender
{

    if([sender isOn])
    {
       _hosStartDateLbl.frame = CGRectMake(_birthLbl.frame.origin.x, _birthLbl.frame.origin.y+_birthLbl.frame.size.height+15,  [_hosStartDateLbl.text sizeWithFont:_hosStartDateLbl.font].width, 17);//birthLbl is created using xib

       [_hosStartDateLbl sizeToFit];

       [self.scroll addSubview:_hosStartDateLbl];

       scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scroll.frame.size.width, _hosStartDateLbl.frame.origin.y+_hosStartDateLbl.frame.size.height+160);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this _hosStartDateLbl = nil; after the line [self.scroll addSubview:_hosStartDateLbl]; of code

Comment: have you enable zombie objects? try to add static frame using CGRectMake(0,0,320,100). and check if you get crashing or not?

Comment: yes tried enabling and disabling zombie ..tired giving hardcoded values also but no luck..the same code works fine in iPad with ios8 and iphone4 with ios7 but its getting failed in iphone5s with ios8